# Class 'Laravel\Passport\Passport' not found on Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-passport

I just `cloned` a `repo` with a `Laravel 5.7 project`, and I am having some troubles to run it on my machine.

When I make a `composer install`, I get this `error`:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In AuthServiceProvider.php line 35:

  Class 'Laravel\Passport\Passport' not found


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

What can I do to solve this error? I dont know where to start.

This is the project's `composer.json file`:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport": "^1.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to do

```
composer update
```

instead of install?

Answer (score 7):

Although `composer update` did the trick depending on situation it might not be the best solution.

First of all - when running `composer install` packages are installed based on versions that are in `composer.lock` if it's included in repository (it should be).

And in your case when you look carefully at console output you had:

> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.

So it's quite possible that someone added Laravel Passport package to `composer.json` but haven't run `composer install` or forgot to commit updated `composer.lock` file.

Now remember when running `composer update` you update all the packages. Sometimes it's fine (only on localhost) but sometimes it's not because not always you want to update all packages. So when you need to update single package you could try in this case also `composer update laravel/passport` just to force updating/installing just Laravel Passport without touching other packages.